# How can I add an amount of widgets in the kv file based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make a program that puts `x` amount of `TextInput`s based on the user's input. I can do that in the py file, but how do I do this in the kv file? I also need to be able to reference these `TextInput`s later on.

This is what I have so far:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class GetCount(Screen):

    count_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def next(self):

        # Setup next screen
        text_inputs = [TextInput(multiline=False) for i in range(int(self.count_input.text))]

        for text_input in text_inputs:
            self.manager.ids.get_input.ids.grid.add_widget(text_input)

        # Switch to next screen
        self.manager.current = "get_input"


class GetInput(Screen):
    pass


kv_file = Builder.load_string("""
ScreenManager:

    GetCount:
        name: "get_count"
        id: get_count

    GetInput:
        name: "get_input"
        id: get_input


<GetCount>:
    
    count_input: count_input
    
    FloatLayout:
        
        Label:
            text: "count"
            size_hint: 1, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"top":0.9}

        TextInput:
            id: count_input 

            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"top":0.7, "x":0.1}
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Next"
            on_release: root.next()
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"top":0.5, "x":0.1}

<GetInput>:
    
    FloatLayout:

        GridLayout:
            id: grid

            cols: 1
    
""")


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv_file


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

The problem is, the `TextInput`s are being added **and created** by the py code, how can I **create** the widget in kv and then **add** it in py?

Comment: You can squash this python code into a kv line, but doing it from Python seems like an easier solution. You can call that Python from kv of course, e.g. via `get_count.next()` in the kv rule you have.

Comment: @inclement, but I want to create the widget in kv then add it. That example is a simple `TextInput`, I want to make more complex widgets in kv then add it via py. Is there a way I can make a widget in kv, reference it in py and add more of that widget from the py?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a widget in kv"?

Comment: @inclement I simply want the widget created in the kv file, not in the py file. Instead of `text_inputs = TextInput(multiline=False)` I want to define these widgets in the kv. What I did here is add them in py file, but that gets messy, I'd rather not import any widgets in py at all

Comment: Ok, I figured out an idea of what to do, but I still have an issue with that. I will post a new and different question.